# How to convert a JsArray to sequence of case classes with spray-json?

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a a variable

```
var movieArray = movieText.parseJson
```

which is of class

```
println(movieArray.getClass)
class spray.json.JsArray
```

How do I convert it to a Sequence of case classes e.g

```
case class Movie(id: Int, title: String)
```

I tried

```
1. movieArray.convertTo[Seq[Movie]]
2. movieArray.map(_.convertTo[Movie])
3. for (i <- movieArray) println(i)
```

gives errors...

```
1. Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for Seq[Movie]
2. value map is not a member of spray.json.JsValue
3. value foreach is not a member of spray.json.JsValue
```

Any suggestions? Help appreciated.

**Correct answer**
https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/259

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

var movieArray = movieText.stripMargin.parseJson

case class Movie(id: Int, title: String)

implicit val movieFormat = jsonFormat2(Movie)

movieArray.convertTo[Seq[Movie]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Each element of movieArray will have to be converted to an object of type Movie.

```
movieArray.map(_.convertTo[Movie])
```

Of course, the above statement depends on availability of logic to convert from Json to instance of Movie (JsonProtocol). Please refer the following for example

https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes

Comment: I get the following error when using map : "value map is not a member of spray.json.JsValue". This means that JsArray doesn't have the map function?

Comment: also `for (i <- movieArray) println(i)` causes an error `value foreach is not a member of spray.json.JsValue`

Comment: .map is available on JsArray, not JsValue. Try thisJsArray(movieArray)

Comment: Steps: to AST `var movieArray = movieText.parseJson` printing class`println(movieArray.getClass)` prints... `class spray.json.JsArray`  map to movie case class`movieArray = movieArray.map(_.convertTo[Movie])` gives error `value map is not a member of spray.json.JsValue`

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean with: thisJsArray(movieArray)

Comment: My bad. I responded without understanding your problem completely.  movieArray.convertTo[Seq[Movie]] should work as long as corresponding JsonProtocol (for conversion from/to json) is available in scope. This can be done by importing JsonProtocol before executing the conversion statement.