# Convert a JsArray of JsArray into into Case class

Tags: scala, playframework, jsvalue

My question is a kind-of extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319629/how-to-convert-a-jsarray-to-sequence-of-case-classes-with-spray-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484474/operation-on-list-after-flatten) one too.

My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "results": [
        {
            "exceed_size": "yes",
            "rows_count": 1001,
            "runtime_seconds": 0.02199999988079071,
            "columns": [
                "COL_1",
                "COL_2",
                "COL_3",
                "COL_4",
                "COL_5",
                "COL_6",
                "COL_7",
                "COL_8",
                "COL_9"
            ],
            "columns_type": [
                "number",
                "string",
                "string",
                "string",
                "number",
                "time",
                "time",
                "number",
                "string"
            ],
            "limit": 1000,
            "index": 0,
            "rows": [
                [
                    "9",
                    " C68894",
                    "                                                                                                    ",
                    "",
                    "0",
                    "2018-05-02 03:13:00.0",
                    "2017-12-02 22:32:00.0",
                    "",
                    "Approved  "
                ],
                [
                    "65",
                    "325806   ",
                    "msm                                                                             ",
                    "                 ",
                    "2",
                    "2018-05-02 03:13:00.0",
                    "2018-07-06 06:00:00.0",
                    "13",
                    "Approved  "
                ],
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm using Play Framework provided JSON Library for JSON Parsing.

If you have a look at the `rows` value, it is a `JsArray` of a `JsArray` of string values. I have been trying to convert `rows` into a List of objects of a case class, where my case class would look like:

`case class Rows(col_1: String, col_2: String, ... , col_9: String)`

I had tried to do something like:

```
val rows = (response \\ "rows").head.as[List[List[(String, String, ... , String)]]].flatten
```

Trying This way threw an error, which I was sure of won't work. How do I convert such a `JsArray` into a List of objects of a case class?

EDIT 1:

As @MilanRegmi suggested, I tried:

```
implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Rows] = Json.format[Rows]

val emails = (response \ "results" \ "rows").as[JsArray]
            .value.map(j => j.validate[Rows].get)
```

Trying this resulted in:

```
Exception in thread "main" play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List([{"exceed_size":"yes","rows_count":1001,"runtime_seconds":0.01600000075995922,"columns":["COL_1","COL_2","COL_3","COL_4","COL_5","COL_6","COL_7","COL_8","COL_9"],"columns_type":["number","string","string","string","number","time","time","number","string"],"limit":1000,"index":0,"rows":[["9"," C68894","","","0","2018-05-02 03:13:00.0","2017-12-02 22:32:00.0","","Approved  "],["65","325806   ","msm                                                                             ","                 ","2","2018-05-02 03:13:00.0","2018-07-06 06:00:00.0","13","Approved  "],...]}] is not an object),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:25)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:25)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:64)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$class.as(JsReadable.scala:23)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsUndefined.as(JsLookup.scala:181)
    at com.cmdwldap.restapi.User.getEntitlementUserData(User.scala:150)
    at com.cmdwldap.restapi.User$.main(User.scala:168)
    at com.cmdwldap.restapi.User.main(User.scala)
```

PS: Line 150 corresponds to the place where `val emails` is mentioned.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `(Json.parse(jsonString) \ "results" \ 0 \ "rows").validate[List[List[String]]]`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
val rows: Seq[Rows] = (json \ "result" \ "rows").as[JsArray].value.map(j => j.validate[Rows].get)
```

**Update:**

After going through your question for several times. I got your question now. You want to convert `List[List[String]` into `CaseClass`.

First, you cannot convert Array of List of String into a case class directly. So, you need to convert `Array[String]` to `JsObject` where `key` should be `fieldName` of the class. After that we can fetch `fieldName` using reflection. Then, we need to create `JsObject` to match `caseClass` and `List[String]` using the `fieldName`.

Pro-grammatically, above explained scenario can be solve in the following way:

```
 case class Rows(col1: Option[String] = None,
               col2: Option[String] = None,
               col3: Option[String] = None,
               col4: Option[String] = None,
               col5: Option[String] = None,
               col6: Option[String] = None,
               col7: Option[String] = None,
               col8: Option[String] = None,
               col9: Option[String] = None)
```

`implicit val reads = Json.reads[Rows]`

This is our case class and the implicits `reads`. Now, the above explained part is below:

`import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`

```
def classAccessors[T: TypeTag]: List[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
  }.toList


 val rowFieldNames = classAccessors[Rows].map(k => k.name.toString)
 val results =  (json \ "results").as[JsArray].value.flatMap{
    r => (r \ "rows").as[JsArray].value
  }.map{row =>
    val rowArray = row.as[JsArray]
    val rowArraySeq = rowArray.value.map(_.as[JsString]).map(_.value)
    val map = rowArraySeq.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, JsValue]){
      (r, c) =>
        val indexOfCurrentValue = rowArraySeq.indexOf(c)
        val fieldName = rowFieldNames(indexOfCurrentValue)
        r.+((fieldName, JsString(c)))
    }
    val rowJsObject = JsObject(map)
    Json.toJson(rowJsObject)
        }.toList
```

Comment: Error: `No implicits found for parameter rds: Reads[Rows]`

Comment: You have missed implicits reads and writes. Add implicit formatter like this: implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Rows] = Json.format[Rows]

Comment: Please check EDIT 1

Comment: It seems like you have provided an invalid json. Please check your json first and make sure it is valid json.

Comment: It is a valid JSON.. :(

Comment: Remove `...` from the json. Your error says `...` is not an object.

Comment: I put `...` to indicate that there are more such values. If I test my JSON without this, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: Then how `...` comes in your exception if you have removed it. You are not getting what I mean. Go through your exception again you will get it by yourself.

Comment: Well, if you see my `rows`, I have 2 arrays in there. What I meant by `...` is that there are many more such arrays in it, and I truncated it by adding `...` . Even if the `...` doesn't exist, the JSON seems perfectly fine with just the 2 arrays in there. The `...` **doesn't come up in the exception**. I put it to truncate.

Comment: Small change in the code instead of `validate[Rows]` can you try `validate[List[Rows]]`

Comment: try to use json as compact form, not pretty look.

Comment: Check the `Update` part in the answer above.

Comment: `List({"col7":"msm                                                                           ","col8":"325806   ","col3":"2018-07-06 06:00:00.0","col6":"                 ","col2":"13","col9":"65","col5":"2","col1":"Approved  ","col4":"2018-05-02 03:13:00.0"},{"col7":"                                                                                                    ","col8":" C68894","col3":"2017-12-02 22:32:00.0","col6":"","col9":"9","col5":"0","col1":"Approved  ","col4":"2018-05-02 03:13:00.0"})`.Your solution kinda worked, but column names in response are not in order, also column ordering